# Unable to find explicit activity class and force close application

Tags: java, android

When I launch my application, it force closes and when I debug my program I kept getting error messages. I have **2 activities**, the Authentication (where User log in) and Mainpage (this is the page when the user is logged in).

The problem here is when i'm **not** logged in, I can still log in. If i'm logged in it should take me to Mainpage (Activity), but now the error [*see below*] shows up.

This is from the **stack trace**:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.blocktrekacademy.officialblocktrek/com.blocktrekacademy.officialblocktrek.Authentication}: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {/com.blocktrekacademy.officialblocktrek.Mainpage}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {/com.blocktrekacademy.officialblocktrek.Mainpage}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

This is the **Application** tag in my **AndroidManifest.xml**:

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".Authentication"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_authentication"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Mainpage"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_mainpage"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
    </application>
```

**Note**:

> My *classes* extends **AppCompatActivity**

**Tried Solutions:**

I tried adding `android:name=".Authentication"` on **Application**, but that gives me this error:

```
'com.blocktrekacademy.officialblocktrek.Authentication' is not assignable to 'android.app.Application'
```

on **AndroidManifest.xml**, and these errors on **logcat**:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.blocktrekacademy.officialblocktrek.Authentication: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.blocktrekacademy.officialblocktrek.Authentication cannot be cast to android.app.Application
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.blocktrekacademy.officialblocktrek.Authentication cannot be cast to android.app.Application
```

I'm really a newbie on Android Development :(

Comment: show your Authentication Activity code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start an activity from another activity with an explicit intent this should work like this (you should probably do the following after having having checked the login credentials):

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, Mainpage.class);
 startActivity(intent);
```

Make sure the activities are in the same package or otherwise adjust the path to MainActivity.class, so that it can be found.

Answer (score 0):

Hi @user7994637 try doing this in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".officialblocktrek.Authentication"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_authentication"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".officialblocktrek.Mainpage"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_mainpage"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
    </application>
```

I guess your activity is inside package "officialblocktrek", hence it crashing so I updated your manifest. Hope it helps.